# H2O package not initiating in R

Tags: r, data-science, h2o

after installing the h2o package in the Rstudio, when I'm initiating `h2o.init()` it is having this problem

> In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :path[1]="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin/bin/java.exe": The system cannot find the path specified

I'm facing this problem even after setting my `java/jdk1.8/bin` as `PATH` in the environment variables.

can anyone help me out to solve this problem

Comment: bin/bin in above path

Comment: there is not bib\bin